# PayPal API shipping options - Cannot add a property that's already present; use replace

Tags: json, paypal

I'm attempting to update shipping options using PayPal Orders API V2 on Sandbox, suffice to say the documentation is pretty hard going to use.

In some instances my website doesn't have any shipping options, so `onShippingAddressChange` I want to remove all shipping options from the popup.

I've found as a value I can set when creating an order, but I can't find anything to patch this value, how can I patch this in my JSON request (and then re-enable if they chose an address I do this to):

```
application_context: {
            shipping_preference: "NO_SHIPPING"
      }
```

Furthermore, when creating the order in the first instance I set a default delivery address, then once the user logs in I have this same `onShippingAddressChange` to get the users address, and attempt to change the shipping options but I consistently get an error. Here's my shipping options JSON and the response. I can't find anything useful to help me understand where the problem is:

My shipping options JSON:

```
[
  {
    "op": "replace",
    "path": "/purchase_units/@reference_id=='default'/shipping/options",
    "value": [
      {
        "id": "177",
        "type": "SHIPPING",
        "label": "Sweden",
        "selected": true,
        "amount": {
          "value": "29.99",
          "currency_code": "GBP"
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "op": "replace",
    "path": "/purchase_units/@reference_id=='default'",
    "value": {
      "amount": {
        "value": "33.98",
        "currency_code": "GBP",
        "breakdown": {
          "shipping": {
            "value": "29.99",
            "currency_code": "GBP"
          },
          "item_total": {
            "value": "3.99",
            "currency_code": "GBP"
          }
        }
      },
      "items": [
        {
          "name": "Pack of cards",
          "quantity": "1",
          "unit_amount": {
            "currency_code": "GBP",
            "value": "3.99"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
]
```

returned error:

```
{
   "name":"UNPROCESSABLE_ENTITY",
   "details":[
      {
         "field":"op",
         "value":"replace",
         "location":"body",
         "issue":"INVALID_PATCH_OPERATION",
         "description":"The operation cannot be honored. Cannot add a property thats already present, use replace. Cannot remove a property thats not present, use add. Cannot replace a property thats not present, use add."
      }
   ],
   "message":"The requested action could not be performed, semantically incorrect, or failed business validation.",
   "debug_id":"XXXXXXXXXXXXX",
   "links":[
      {
         "href":"https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/orders/v2/#error-INVALID_PATCH_OPERATION",
         "rel":"information_link",
         "method":"GET"
      }
   ]
}
```

Can anyone spot what I'm doing wrong? or experienced this problem and have a solution please?

Answer (score 0):

Here's my solution:

```
 [   {
     "op": "replace",
     "path": "/purchase_units/@reference_id=='default'/shipping/options",
     "value": [
       {
         "id": "29",
         "type": "SHIPPING",
         "label": "Standard",
         "selected": true,
         "amount": {
           "value": "3.99",
           "currency_code": "GBP"
         }
       },
       {
         "id": "4",
         "type": "SHIPPING",
         "label": "Collection in Person",
         "selected": false,
         "amount": {
           "value": "0.00",
           "currency_code": "GBP"
         }
       }
     ]   },   {
     "op": "replace",
     "path": "/purchase_units/@reference_id=='default'/amount",
     "value": {
       "value": "43.89",
       "currency_code": "GBP",
       "breakdown": {
         "item_total": {
           "currency_code": "GBP",
           "value": "33.20"
         },
         "tax_total": {
           "currency_code": "GBP",
           "value": "6.70"
         },
         "shipping": {
           "currency_code": "GBP",
           "value": "3.99"
         }
       }
     }   } ]
```

Making sure I don't return a Promise.reject() in the JS - and I do this by checking the shipping option array length:

```
onShippingAddressChange: function (data, actions) {

                                            var dataIn =
                                            {
                                                actions:
                                                {
                                                    "payPalSmartPayPatchOrder":
                                                    {
                                                        payPalData: data
                                                    }
                                                }
                                            };

                                            return fetch("/Handlers/ProcessBasket", {
                                                method: "post",
                                                headers: {
                                                    "Content-Type": "application/json",
                                                },
                                                body: JSON.stringify(dataIn)
                                            }).then(function (res) {
                                                if (!res || res.error) return actions.reject();
                                                var promise = res.json();
                                                return promise;

                                            }).then(function (data) {
                                                if (data.shippingOptions == null || data.shippingOptions.length == 0)
                                                    return Promise.reject();
                                            });
```

When you do this you get a response back that looks like, which is fine. Only if ou get a Result value is there a problem:

> Id = 2748, Status = RanToCompletion, Method = "{null}", Result = ""